# Swift 4 - imageview with two rounded corners in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, swift4

I have a UIImageView inside of a UICollectionView Cell and I wanna make it' s top corners rounded. I couldn' t solve on my on, any help is appreciated.

You can see cell has 10px corner radius and I want same effect to be applied on image too.

[image: Endeksa]

Comment: What's the code that you've written to top corner the image view?

Comment: As long as the cell's `clipsToBounds = true` and the imageview is a subview of that cell's contentView you should be good to go (assuming that you have used `cornerRadius` to get the rounded corners)

Comment: @Alladinian clipsToBound=true, self.layer.cornerRadius=10 and imageview is a subview but still not working

Comment: Well it sounds ok (I mean it _should_ be working)... Have you tried the "Debug view hierarchy" tool in order to inspect your cells? Also, if you hide the image, do you get rounded corners at the top of the cell?

Comment: @Alladinian the below answer worked correctly. I was calling it from the wrong place.. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try `UIRectCorner` [Document here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirectcorner)

here my custom class [AGRoundCornersView](https://gist.github.com/AshvinGudaliya/068d296fd3f97b5be7865198a22b12d1)

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = shape
    }
}
```

code :

**1. Call When View is resized.**

```
uiimage.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10)
```

**2. Create custom class**

```
class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Call when view is resize.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

In your collectionview cell, put the below two lines of code & you are good to go. No need to write any extension:

```
cell._imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell._imageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

Here corner radius will apply **TopLeft & TopRight** corners & rest of corners will remain same.

If you want to apply the corner radius in **BottomLeft & BottomRight** corners, then **maskedCorners** should look like the below:

```
cell._imageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your UICollectionViewCell

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image.roundCorners([.topRight,.topLeft], radius: 8)
            self.image.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [AshvinGudaliya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48519560/1371853) and [Sujewan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50759305/1371853)

Following code worked for my collection cell's ImageView Top Left-Right corners

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:TUGBucketCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! TUGBucketCell
        //Rounded corner ImageView
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.imgVw.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10)
            cell.imgVw.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }

        return cell
    }
```

and the extension is

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = shape
    }
}
```